# Terraform script api_gateway with lambda integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, integration

I have created the following terraform script -

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda_function" {
    function_name              = "Lambda-Demo-AG"
    package_type               = "Image"
    image_uri                  = "###########"
    role                       = aws_iam_role.role.arn
    memory_size                = 256
    timeout                    = 30
    tracing_config {
        mode = "PassThrough"
    } 
}

# IAM
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name               = "myrole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda_function.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.arn
}

###API Gateway####

# API Gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api" {
  name = "myapi"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "resource" {
  path_part   = "resource"
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.root_resource_id
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda_function.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "apideploy" {
   depends_on = [
     aws_api_gateway_integration.integration,
   ]

   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
   stage_name  = "test"
}
```

When I Hit the API the lambda function is not being triggered for some reason. The message I get is {"message": "Internal server error"}. This is when I hit the path for example https://#########.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/resource When I hit the root https://#########.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test I get an {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} although there was no authentication set? I have gone into the console in API gateway I can see that the correct Lambda is integrated. If I got into the Lambda console the Lambda function specified does not have api gateway as a trigger in the Diagram UI. I have cloudwatch configured and can't see that the lambda function is being invoked.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the issue - there was a problem with the way I was setting up the source_arn in aws_lambda_permissions. One I changed this I was able to invoke the lambda function.

Comment: Please be specific about the problem and the solution. It can help others.